# Equivalent of BeanUtils.getProperty() in Guava

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

What is Guava's version of BeanUtils.getProperty() implementation?
I am bit new Guava library. Could not find anything similar in Guava's reflection library.
Need it to write JSR 303 custom validators.

```
final String fieldValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, fieldName);
```

Comment: [`Properties.getPropertyByName(Object bean, String propertyName)`](https://guava-reflection.googlecode.com/svn/maven-site-repository/apidocs/com/google/code/guava/beans/Properties.html#getPropertyByName%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @Tunaki Where can I find this `Properties.getPropertyName`?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav click on the link in Tunaki's comment.

Comment: @Tunaki, that's not part of Guava, that's just from some random other library that calls itself Guava Reflection.  Guava has no reflective utilities for this operation, and I'm not sure why the OP assumed it did.

Comment: @Tunaki Agree with @LouisWasserman, Eclipse does not recognize `com.google.code.guava.beans.Properties`

Comment: Why do you need a Guava equivalent?